# Keep a class instance allocated until the program ends without using NSObject?

Tags: swift, nsobject, nsnotifications

I'm writing a UserNotification library to reuse in many apps. The below .swift file is just dragged into a new project when needed. I'm then adding an NSObject to the View Controller Scene, setting it's custom class to KTUserNotification. I then drag a referencing outlet from this NSObject into the view controller. From there I use this outlet to call Show() to display notifications.

I use the NSObject with a custom class approach because the instance needs to stay allocated until the app ends. I first tried making it just a custom class, using let usernotification = KTUserNotification(). This however deallocated before the call came through to the "shouldPresent notification", causing a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The @IBInspectables were just a nice addition I tossed in when moving to the NSObject approach.

Is there another way of keeping the instance allocated until the program ends without using an NSObject? Os is the NSObject the best way to go here?

```
import Cocoa

class KTUserNotification: NSObject, NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    @IBInspectable var showEvenIfAppIsFocus: Bool = true
    @IBInspectable var title: String = ""
    @IBInspectable var subTitle: String = ""
    @IBInspectable var informativeText: String = ""

    @IBAction func showNotification(_ sender: Any) {
        Show()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        NSUserNotificationCenter.default.delegate = self
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: NSUserNotificationCenter, shouldPresent notification: NSUserNotification) -> Bool {
        return showEvenIfAppIsFocus
    }

    public func Show(title : String, subTitle: String, informativeText : String) {
        let notification = NSUserNotification()
        let randIdentifier = Int(arc4random_uniform(999999999) + 1)
        notification.identifier = "KTUserNotification\(randIdentifier)"
        notification.title = title
        notification.subtitle = subTitle
        notification.informativeText = informativeText
        notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName        
        let notificationCenter = NSUserNotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter.deliver(notification)
    }

    public func Show() {
        Show(title: title, subTitle: subTitle, informativeText: informativeText)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong about NSObject? It could be a question if it had only functions. But since you have properties (title, subtitle, etc),  NSObject is a right thing. BTW, I wounder if @IBInspectable properties are allowed for a class that doesn't implement NSObjectProtocol.

Comment: It says that "The Cocoa root class NSObject adopts this protocol, so all objects inheriting from NSObject have the features described by this protocol" so I assumed that it was?

I still kind of wonder though if there are more ways of having an instance of a class kept until the program terminates, or is the NSObject the only way? Not that I have anything against the NSObject approach.